# How to recognize different-colored objects in an image matching the template of the query image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection, template-matching

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

dir = 'C:\\Project\\Interview Packet'
os.chdir(dir)

image = cv2.imread('us_flag_color.png')
template = cv2.imread('mask.png')

imageGray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
templateGray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

template = cv2.Canny(template, 50, 200)

result = cv2.matchTemplate(imageGray, templateGray, cv2.TM_SQDIFF)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

w, h = template.shape[:2]
threshold = 0.8*max_val
loc = np.where( result >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(image, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)

cv2.imwrite("res.png", image)
```

I've a US flag with stars on it and a mask image consisting a black star. Using the mask image I would like to detect all the stars in the US flag albeit colored differently. When I use the above code I could only get the stars labelled white recognized as illustrated by the below picture.

[image]

The box colored red has a star under it colored black matching that of the one in the mask image. I'm guessing this is because I'm using the gray image to identify these stars. As shown below the colored stars are faded in the process of graying that the algorithm is not able to distinguish them from the background color.

[image]

The original images are posted below:

- mask: [image]
- us flag: [image]

Comment: Could you please post the original input images as well? (`us_flag_color.png` and `mask.png`)

Comment: Since it's the colour that differentiates the object, I would consider working with HSV or HSI colourspace, rather than just grayscale version of the RGB image.

Comment: @DanMašek added now.

Comment: For detection the stars in this image, the `V(HSV)` is better than `gray`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually，I process image with color info in `HSV` color space. I analysis the different channel in `RGB` and `HSV`, and find the `V` channel is the best for this question.

The `BGR`:

[image]

The `HSV`:

[image]

Then do template matching, I get this:

[image]

---

I think maybe use `findContours` will also do the work.

Comment: can you please let me know how to control the thickness of the bounding boxes.I tried the following code and I get very thick bounding boxes that overlap with the stars. Please let me know how to reproduce the thickness of the boxes in your output.

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(image, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 1, 8)

Comment: If you check the `loc` found by thresholded `cv2.minMaxLoc` result, you will find there are more than one pts in every region. And I adjust the ratio to `0.9`, so the pts become less, and the boxes seem thinner(but till more than one box for every star), so you just cann't really control the boxes' thinkness of every star. As I said, `findContours` would work better, because it find only one contour every star.